# Invalid format exception for UTC - joda time

Tags: java, jodatime

I am using jodatime 2.9.9. I am trying to parse the client side date time. The client side date time comes as GMT or UTC. If it is UTC, it throws invalid format exception.

```
public static Date convertToGMT(String datetime) {      
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = null;
    if(datetime.contains("GMT")){
        formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E MMM dd yyyy 
 HH:mm:ss 'GMT'");
    } else if(datetime.contains("UTC")) {
        formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E MMM dd yyyy 
HH:mm:ss 'UTC'");
    }   
    datetime = datetime.split("-")[0];
    logger.info("gmt time from client side:" + datetime + ":");
    DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(datetime);
    Date gmttime = dt.toDate();
    return gmttime;
}
```

### **Logger output**

gmt time from client side:**Tue Apr 23 06:44:45 UTC**

### **Sample exception:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Tue Apr 23 06:44:45 UTC" is malformed at ":44:45 UTC"
```

Please help.

Comment: Your pattern contains `yyyy` but there is no year in the input.

Comment: Oh, you are so right. So, the input is the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Or you can change the pattern to match the input.

Comment: I found the reason to be unsupported version of IE used in the client PC.